# Having problems with IJavaElement/IType (of a class) - how to get the IType of the superclass 

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, superclass

In an eclipse plugin, given that I'm holding an IJavaElement (also IType) of a Java class
org.eclipse.jdt.core.IType

How do I get the IType (or some other object representation, like IJavaElement) of its superclass?
I don't want to use the newSupertypeHierarchy() because that is too much overhead.
I just want the direct, one level up, superclass...
I tried all of the following methods
(in the code below 'subType' is a IJavaElement representation of a class whose superclass I want to get):

```
System.out.println("subType root: "+((IType) subType).getTypeRoot().getElementName());
System.out.println("subType primary: "+subType.getPrimaryElement().getElementName());
System.out.println("subType ansc: "+((IType) subType).getAncestor(0));
System.out.println("subType dclr:"+((IType) subType).getDeclaringType());
System.out.println("subType parnt: "+((IType) subType).getParent().getElementName());
```

None of them produced the super class

Comment: Doesn't `getSuperClass` do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

There is **IType.getSuperclassName()**, but that will just give you the SimpleName of the superclass. The problem is, that the superclass may not be in the same project or may even be in some library jar. That is why it takes more ressources to calculate.

AFAIK this is the best way to get the IType of the superclass:

```
public static IType getSupertypeOf(final IType type, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
    return type.newSupertypeHierarchy(monitor).getSuperclass(type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.println("subType getSuperClass: "+((subType.class).getSuperClass().getName());
```

Comment: i get compile errors since subType is of type IType the compiler complains about the expression 'subType.class'. IType is an interface. so i can do IType.class or subType.getClass() but that does not get me in the right path.